# Как сверстать блок с изображением?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Всем привет. Объясните, пожалуйста, как добавить выделенного синим человечка? Через img, или background-image, или есть иные способы? Какое решение будет бестпрактис?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: img, svg. В чем конкретно вопрос? Сверстать кодом, за Вас это делать вряд ли кто-то будет. Или приведите код Вашей попытки, что конкретно у Вас не получается.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, уточнил

Comment: Теперь вопрос, на который нельзя дать однозначный ответ. Используйте то, что Вам удобнее. Нет точного ответа. Оба варианта применимы.